# Terminal multiplexer for different sized windows

Tags: terminal, screen, tmux

I'm using tmux as my muliplexer. Is there an alternative that handles multiple windows of different sizes?

My Usecase:

I'm developing in vscode. I use the small embedded terminal to issue commands and want to read the output on a second, bigger screen. Attaching a tmux session won't work because the attached session window is as small as the original.